# What is HttpEngine in android.net.http

Tags: android, http, android-networking

I noticed there are new class in the [android.net.http](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/http/package-summary) package. Some of them are added in API 34, also in the S Extensions 7. I encountered the [HttpEngine](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/http/HttpEngine) class in the package, the summary says that

> An engine to process UrlRequests, which uses the best HTTP stack available on the current platform. An instance of this class can be created using HttpEngine.Builder.

Is this class noteworthy? What is meant by "best HTTP stack", would it perform better than typical HTTP client we use like OkHttp?